# intel centrino wireless n 1030 wireless drop after reboot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi suddenly stopped working even after reboot

`sudo lshw -C network` gives this

```
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface 
  product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
  physical id: 0 
  bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0 
  logical name: eth0 version: 06 
  serial: 24:b6:fd:27:e1:b8 
  size: 10Mbit/s 
  capacity: 1Gbit/s 
  width: 64 bits 
  clock: 33MHz 
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s 
  resources: irq:30 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f1104000-f1104fff memory:f1100000-f1103fff 
*-network 
   description: Ethernet interface 
   physical id: 2 
   logical name: usb0 
   serial: fa:dd:3b:86:b9:76 
   capabilities: ethernet 
   physical configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.167 link=yes multicast=yes
```

My wifi device is intel centrino wireless n 1030 (rainbow peak)

---

i tried changing the iwlwifi.conf but could not be of any help 
then on the website i found a download 
https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

these were the instructions given
To install firmware:

```
Copy the files into the distribution-specific firmware directory, /lib/firmware.
If the directory does not work, consult your distribution documentation.
If you configure the kernel yourself, make sure firmware loading is enabled.
```

please note there are other two files than the iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode file which does not require to be copied (one is license and the other is readme) 
and then it was up again

however a new problem was encountered
wifi dropping after few hours

dmesg | grep iwl gives the follwoing

```
[   20.654434] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   21.575195] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   21.575199] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   21.575200] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   21.575203] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[   21.575256] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.595943] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   27.574648] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   27.581175] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   27.581262] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[   27.648799] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   27.655322] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   27.655409] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 2240.088860] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 2240.095386] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 2240.095475] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 2240.163097] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 2240.169634] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 2240.169729] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
```

i aslo have refrred to the bug reporting https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1420935
have tried the following 
Create a file named: /etc/modprobe.d/wifi_bug.conf

Add the following lines to the file:
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1

Set the file's ownership the same as other files in that folder.

Reboot.

worked for a while , problem persists 
as of now the kernel version i am using is 4.4.0-130-generic

Comment: @Zanna after the above  the wifi adapter was up , but a new issue of wifi drop after few hours was noted . please add the needful .

Comment: What exactly did you change in the `iwlwifi.conf`?

Comment: @Thomas options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
to options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8

Comment: @Thomas and then since it didnt work then i reverted back to the previous that is options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

Comment: @Pilot6 please let me know what else needs to be added.. this was all i did, awaiting your help !

Comment: @sassy.geek Don't use "post Answer" - use the "Edit" button on your question to add information.  I've merged your not-an-answer into your original question as an edit for now, but keep this in mind going forward please that additional inofrmation should be added as edits to your question, and not 'answers'.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks ! will surely keep it in mind :)

Comment: @sassy.geek Please post output of `dmesg | grep iwl` to your question

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the backup , kindly also look in to the issue of wifi drop after few hours !

Comment: one more thing that i noticed was while changing the iwlwifi.conf there were multiple files of the same created . i deleted them all and then only one file with the line iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 was present 
it worked good but there were issues again after some update

Comment: have found that this issue is fixed in higer upgrades of ubuntu so i am upgrading today

Comment: i have posted a similar question for 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051149/intel-centrino-wireless-n-1030-wireless-drop-after-reboot-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: one thing i did not try is adding r8168-dkms via synaptic packet manager . please ref to the similar question posted for 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051149/intel-centrino-wireless-n-1030-wireless-drop-after-reboot-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hardware Testing Required**

https://askubuntu.com/a/1065770/623433

this is the solution that worked for me

Comment: After the test did you install new hardware?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i have mentioned in a comment stating that , i called the dell engineer to pay a visit for service , he came , opened the laptopp, cleaned upa abit by removing almost all the chips i cant tell , but surely the wifi card was removed and cleaned as well and to my surprise , the wifi started working ! i have accepted : futher hardware testing as the most suitable answer for me !
i have also tested it with 14.04 and 18.04 on live sticks by multiple reboot.

Answer (score 0):

From this answer: [Reset WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/a/1066728/307523) you can power your WiFi off and on again after a reboot. This will simulate the physical power button cycling off and on which works for your laptop.