# Dual booting: every time Windows boots, it increases the scrolling speed of the mouse on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

My friend has [Microsoft Wireless Desktop 850 with AES (PY9-00001)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014N53JVO) Ubuntu 18.04. The scrolling speed is too fast, but if he removes the USB dongle and plugs it in again, it [fixes the problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/360045/23239).

He's on a dual booted PC, and every time he boots Windows then boots back into Ubuntu, the problem is back.

How can we fix it for good?

The problem only occurs after soft reboot only.

`lsusb` when the mouse is working perfectly

[image: lsusb output in terminal]

`lsusb` when it's not working, when booting Windows then Ubuntu

[image: identical lsusb output]

---

When the mouse is working as expected, `lsmod` outputs

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
mei_me                 40960  0
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                24576  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
intel_smartconnect     16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
uas                    24576  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            69632  3 uas
i915                 1617920  66
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mxm_wmi                16384  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
drm                   401408  11 i915,drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
video                  45056  1 i915
wmi                    24576  1 mxm_wmi
```

---

When the mouse is not working as it should, `lsmod` outputs

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 40960  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
intel_smartconnect     16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
uas                    24576  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            69632  3 uas
mxm_wmi                16384  0
i915                 1617920  56
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
ahci                   36864  3
r8169                  86016  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  7 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    24576  1 mxm_wmi
video                  45056  1 i915
```

The output of `xinput`:

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/bus/usb/003/003 
[sudo] password for nad: 
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: status error on /dev/bus/usb/003/003: No such file or directory
lsof 4.89
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-E] [+|-e s] [+|-f[gG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

`lsmod` without plugging in the mouse dongle (so the mouse and keyboard combo are unplugged)

```
Module                  Size  Used by
usbhid                 49152  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm_intel             208896  0
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
mei_me                 40960  0
pcbc                   16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mac_hid                16384  0
intel_smartconnect     16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
uas                    24576  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            69632  3 uas
i915                 1617920  67
mxm_wmi                16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  12 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    24576  1 mxm_wmi
video                  45056  1 i915
```

My friend used to use an HP wireless mouse with a wired keyboard and everything was fine. When he bought that Microsoft wireless mouse/keyboard combo, he started facing the problem listed above.

---

`xinput list-props 9`

```
Device 'Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0':
    Device Enabled (140):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (275):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (276):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (260): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (261):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (262):    0, 0
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (264):    1118, 1861
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (291):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (292):   1
```

`xinput list-props 11`

```
Device 'Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0':
    Device Enabled (140):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (275):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (276):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (277):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (278):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (279):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (280): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (281): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (282):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (283):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (284): -1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (285): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (286):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (287):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (288):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (289): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (290): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (260): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (261):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (262):    0, 0
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (264):    1118, 1861
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (291):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (292):   1
```

`usb-devices`

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=8008 Rev=00.05
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=8000 Rev=00.05
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=10
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=09 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=058f ProdID=9254 Rev=03.12
S:  Manufacturer=ALCOR
S:  Product=Generic USB Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1058 ProdID=1021 Rev=20.21
S:  Manufacturer=Western Digital
S:  Product=Ext HDD 1021
S:  SerialNumber=574341575A31353030303333
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=03 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=045e ProdID=0745 Rev=06.76
S:  Manufacturer=Microsoft
S:  Product=Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Comment: It is only after soft boot, right? Looks like windows does not unload the device firmware. Run lsusb and find which device driver it uses. Get back when you have the info.

Comment: @kukulo yes It is only after soft boot, and I edited my question to include `lsusb` output

Comment: what is the output of lsmod command?

Comment: @kukulo I just edited the question to include `lsmod`

Comment: lsof /dev/bus/usb/003/003  -use this command and get the output. If you get privilege error use sudo in front of the command

Comment: @kukulo do i run it twice, when the mouse is working and when it's not.. or only when it's not working?

Comment: run it once, i am trying to figure out which device driver is in use for your usb bluetooth mouse

Comment: `xinput list`, get device ID, then `xinput list-props <id>`, post before and after

Comment: Just to be clear it's only after a hard boot / cold boot the mouse works fine. It's during a soft boot / reboot that the mouse is defective? The question wording implies the opposite.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix what you said is correct and I fixed the wording

Comment: @Lynob Is there a reason you haven't checked the `xinput` properties?

Comment: @kukulo I posted the output you requested at the end

Comment: @rtaft I posted the output you requested right before the end, which id to pick?

Comment: @Lynob both 9 and 11, just looking to see if these values change between boots

Comment: @rtaft okay will include these in 2 days at most, because most probably I'll see my friend in 2 days

Comment: @rtaft I added the output at the bottom

Comment: try to issue these commands, if it helps with the mouse: sudo rmmod usbhid       ,  sudo modprobe usbhid

Comment: @kukulo just tried, no luck, didn't work

Comment: What is the output of the command sudo rmmod usbhid?

Comment: @kukulo will post the output tomorrow and notify you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, the KISS (Keep It Simply Stupid) answer is:

- *Shut down* Windows
- Press the power button to boot into Ubuntu.

#### Why?

The Windows driver leaves the mouse in an unstable state and none of the [really smart answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064744/344926) seem to work, which leads me to the conclusion that *Ubuntu cannot solve this Windows problem.*

<sub>You can still file a bug to the developers of the driver (which is off-topic here), but this is a side-effect and notoriously difficult to debug.  Expect to spend a lot of time on this if you go that way</sub>

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to accept your answer but it seems unfair to the users who  posted those really smart answers and wasted times testing different scripts, I don't know what to do

Comment: I agree with you: I'd feel bad if I were in your shoes as well. See the answer on meta.  **;-)**

Answer (score 6):

## Reset mouse

Windows has a habit of leaving devices in an unusual state when it reboots. It works fine when you reboot from Windows into Windows but there are problems rebooting from Windows into Grub and then into Ubuntu.

The OP's question is just one example where the mouse has incorrect scrolling speed. Other examples include Windows powering off Audio Cards, WiFi or Network adapters can also occur.

---

Here is a new script I've tested and doesn't lock up the mouse/keyboard like the first script did.

Add this script to `/usr/local/bin/reset-usb`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: /usr/local/bin/reset-usb
# DATE: August 17, 2018.
# DESC: Written for Ask Ubuntu Question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061754
#       Reboots / resets all USB devices including mouse & WiFi

if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then # root powers needed to call this script
    echo $0 must be called with sudo powers
    exit 1
fi

for i in /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[uoex]hci_hcd/*:*; do
  [ -e "$i" ] || continue
  echo "${i##*/}" > "${i%/*}/unbind"
  echo "${i##*/}" > "${i%/*}/bind"
done

systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

exit 0
```

Mark the file as executable with:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/reset-usb
```

Edit the file `/etc/rc.local` and insert these lines **before** the last line that says `exit 0`:

```bash
# Reboot / reset all USB devices
/usr/local/bin/reset-usb
```

**Credit**: [How do you reset a USB device from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/290519/307523)

---

**NOTE:** When internal USB devices are reset the WiFi / Bluetooth are reinitialized so `systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81908/discussion-on-answer-by-wineunuuchs2unix-dual-booting-every-time-windows-boots).

Answer (score 2):

The mouse must have DPI setting that windows modified when it starts up. Normally for best response, the system will disable software mouse acceleration and set the mouse DPI to a value that provide the desire movement speed.

When you reboot back to Ubuntu without power cycle the mouse the DPI setting is still at the level that is set by Windows. However, Ubuntu by default have mouse accerelartion set to more than x 1 speed, and hence you experience the faster motion.

You can remove mouse acceleration in Ubuntu so that you can switch between Windows and Ubuntu to get similar mouse movement speed but you may get a very slow mouse motion if you power on to Ubuntu directly unless your mouse support DPI setting memory that doesn't change over power cycle.

Remove mouse acceleration in Ubuntu, create the following file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-accel-disable.conf
```

Content of the file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Microsoft Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
EndSection
```

Restart your session for this change to take into use (i.e., logout/login)

Comment: Okay sir, I feel this would work, I'll test it in 2 days from now, because right now my friend left and tomorrow I have work all day, I'll let you know if it works. Thank you

Comment: Just tried, that did not work, I don't know why, I felt that this must work